# Label called outside the loop isn't accessible from outside the loop?

Tags: c

This is the code I was debugging, when I found this(I find interesting).

```
int function(void) {
    static int i, state = 0;
    switch (state) {
        case 0: goto LABEL0;
        case 1: goto LABEL1;
    }
    LABEL0: /* start of function */
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        state = 1; /* so we will come back to LABEL1 */
        return i;
        LABEL1:; /* resume control straight after the return */
    }
}
```

So what I observed is that this statement -`goto LABEL1;` never moves the PC directly to the code after the label **WHEN THE LABEL IS INSIDE A LOOP**. So far so good. Things went really messy when I changed the code to this and debugged again:

```
int function(void) {
    static int i, state = 0;
    switch (state) {
        case 0: goto LABEL0;
        case 1: goto LABEL1;
    }
   for(;;){
       i++;
    LABEL0: /* start of function */
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        state = 1; /* so we will come back to LABEL1 */
        return i;
        LABEL1:; /* resume control straight after the return */
    }
   }
}
```

I deliberately nested `LABEL0` into loop so I can confirm the results observed. Though the observations didn't confirm the expected result. This time the `goto` statement sent the program directly to the code after the label it refers to (`LABEL0:)`, despite the label was nested into the dummy `for(;;)` loop.

I really hope you get the scenario. Can anyone explain the behavior(I can't find consistency in)?

Comment: C or C++, pick one.

Comment: Just don't write spaghetti like this.

Comment: It is not about the code quality. It is about `defined` or may be `undefined` behavior.

Comment: You might want to add the "language-lawyer" tag then, to show that this is not a real-world program and that you are only interested in the language behavior.

Comment: I would not trust the debugger to show the PC very accurately; Try to put a dummy statement after `LABEL1` in the first example, I guess the PC will be set there if you do that.

Comment: @alain Put it as an answer, so I can check it as a valid answer. You are right, I guess it is some kind of compiler optimisation.

Comment: @Hairi `goto` is a high-level flow control keyword just like `if` statements and loops, so it isn't as simple as just setting the program counter. The functions setjmp/longjmp are closer to such low-level behavior. Though be aware that using those functions is even worse practice than using goto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger does often not show the PC very accurately, because a single source line consists of multiple opcodes, and sometimes of no opcodes at all, so it can't always map the PC to the correct source line.

Put a dummy statement after `LABEL1` in the first example to see if the PC is set there.

An alternative is to switch to the 'disassembly view' or similar if your debugger supports it.

Comment: Good debuggers support op code level stepping/breakpoints. With a good debugger, you'd be able to see exactly which instruction(s) that the C code corresponds to, and you would get an exact match between the code and the program counter. So this might actually just be a bad choice of tools (*cougheclipsesuckscough*).